# What is the best way to display unique product in an eCommerce application

Tags: website-design, e-commerce

I am practicing designing an eCommerce application and I realized that if I want to display a particular product I have to do so using a unique identifier such as the product id.

I noticed a drawback. If a user bookmarks that product with the URL of lets say `example.com/product/<productId>` or adds it to the cart and somewhere down the line that product is deleted from the database, the users bookmark will be useless because that `productId` no longer exists and if that item was previously in the cart that will also be useless.

Can someone please suggest a way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A product should never be deleted from the database. Use a flag indicating if the product is active or inactive.

When the user navigates to an inactive product through a bookmark or a cart, display some of the details of the product and a large message saying that this product is not available anymore. Below this message list alternative products that can be used to replace the inactive product.

Comment: @Flashspeedlife And, of course, inactive (but not simply "out of stock") products would not show up in a normal search (but you might have an option to include them, so users _without_ a bookmark, but who had bought the product, can look up the details). If for some reason you _must_ delete entries from the database, references to such products would produce a "_This product no longer exists (or you have used an invalid product code)_" message (though the clumsiness of that phrasing is another reason not to delete "dead" product lines).

Comment: @DesignerAnalyst Thank you for that piece of knowledge :).

Is there ever an appropriate time when a product should or can be deleted from the database by an admin for example?

Comment: @FlashspeedIfe it should never be deleted. I do not see any reason why you should delete it, disk space and performance is no longer a problem.

Comment: @FlashspeedIfe Even if you are never going to provide an item again, apart from keeping a record of its existence for the reasons you're asking about (keeping links "alive" to some degree) you may still want to retain stuff like sales-data/profitability to inform decisions about stocking new, similar items. The potential space/performance gains by deleting are virtually zero and are very unlikely to exceed the potential "business" gains from keeping the data.